# Remove fillRect rectangles

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, 2d

I am trying to make a simple game that will have squares of random size and color appear at a random location on the screen and you have to click on them. The more you click the higher your score.

I have everything working except, I have no idea how to make it so that when you click on a square it disappears.

Here is my rectangle code

```
g.fillRect(Cube.cubePosX, Cube.cubePosY, Cube.cubeSize, Cube.cubeSize);
```

The position, size, and color are already predetermined and randomly selected in another class file.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- Don't hard code the Rectangles that you're drawing.
- Instead create a collection of Rectangles such as an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` that are drawn in a for loop in the `paintComponent(...)` method of your drawing JPanel.
- Then you remove them from the ArrayList when the user clicks on them.
- This would be done in a MouseListener and again uses a for loop,
- but a key being that this loop iterates backwards. The reason for this is that the Rectangles on "top" of all the others are the last ones drawn. They should be the first ones removed if clicked on.
- You would call `repaint()` on the drawing JPanel (or JComponent) after removing a Rectangle.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks and 1+ back to you!

Comment: @camickr: thanks, and 1+ to you for an alternative viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to make a simple game that will have squares of random size and color appear at a random location on the screen and you have to click on them

You can also use Swing components for this. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more ideas. You would add a MouseListener to each component and you can just remove the component from the panel when it is clicked.

Even if you don't want to use components, you should still consider using a Shape so your game can have more shapes than just rectangles. In this case Howevercraft's suggestions would all apply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep some kind of cache which tells you where these rectangles are.

You should use this cache to not only detect when they are clicked, but also to paint them.

Take a look at [How to create a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

You make also find [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) of some use